# Number Objects Passed Into Functions by Reference

Tags: javascript, object

I was reading [somewhere](http://conceptf1.blogspot.com/2013/11/javascript-closures.html) that when we pass an object into a function "...JavaScript always uses the Object by reference when it passes as argument..." What I think this implies is (correct me if I'm wrong) is that if the function was to modify the object in some way, it would change the original defined object. I tried illustrating this with some code and it does do what I think it does but when I try the example in the blog post with a Number obj, it doesn't change the original value in that object. Please see my jsbin: https://jsbin.com/wociro/edit?js,console,output

```js
console.clear();
/**myobject Object**/
function myobject() {
  this.value = 5;
}
var o = new myobject();
console.log("Original value of o: " + o.value); // o.value = 5

function objectchanger(fnc) {
  fnc.value = 6;
}

objectchanger(o);
console.log("New value of o: " + o.value); // o.value is now equal to 6

/*Number Object*/

var num2 = new Number(2);
console.log("Original value of num2: " + num2);

function numberChanger(fnc) {
  return fnc + 1;
}
console.log("num2 after running numberChanger: " + numberChanger(num2));

console.log("New value of num2: " + num2); //looks the same
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Number is, whatchamacallit... [a primitive.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive)

Comment: In the future, please include all code in the question itself, rather than on another site.

Answer (score 2):

Number objects are still objects. So their value is a reference, and if a function alters a property of an object passed as an argument, that object will be affected outside the function.

```js
function changer(obj) {
  obj.foo = 'bar';
}
var num = new Number(123);
console.log(num.foo); // undefined
changer(num);
console.log(num.foo); // 'bar'
```

However, the value wrapped inside the number object is not stored as a property. It's stored as a [[NumberData]] internal slot. ECMAScript provides no way to alter that slot, so you can't change the number.

Your attempt of `fnc+1` unwraps the number object to get its [[NumberData]], and adds `1` to that. But the result is just discarded, it's not stored back in the [[NumberData]] slot of `fnc`.

If you want to be able to achieve something analogous to changing the [[NumberData]], you can

```js
function MyNumber(num) {
  this.__number__ = +num;
}
MyNumber.prototype = Object.create(Number.prototype);
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Number.prototype).forEach(function(prop) {
  var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Number.prototype, prop);
  if(desc && desc.value && typeof desc.value == 'function') {
    var native = desc.value;
    desc.value = function() {
      return native.apply(this.__number__, arguments);
    };
    Object.defineProperty(MyNumber.prototype, prop, desc);
  }
});
var num = new MyNumber(123);
console.log(+num, num+'', num.toFixed(2)); // 123, "123", "123.00"
num.__number__ = 456;
console.log(+num, num+'', num.toFixed(2)); // 456, "456", "456.00"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Was not aware of the internal details.

Comment: All that and you didn't bring the "immutability" to the table. 
I am so impressed.

Comment: Hm that makes a lot of sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, objects refer to an array, indicated by [] or an object {}. You can verify the type of the variable by using typeof. These are passed by reference.

```
typeof [2, 5, 3] //object
typeof { a: 10} // object
```

If you pass the object literal to a function and modify the value of the property 'a', it would result in the value being modified.

Comment: Hmm but when I run typeof a. I get "object" back

Comment: Apologies, had not run my example through the console. My answer was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a lot issues when I started getting into the object side of JavaScript myself. Best way I can explain is by these examples.

**Objects link.**

```
var obj = {a: 5};
var b = obj.a;
b = 2;
// obj.a: 2
// b: 2
```

This will link to the object value I believe. So if you change `b` it will also change `obj.a`.

**HTML DOM object link with odd behavior**

```
var x = document.getElementById("some_div_id");
x.innerHTML = "example"; // this works

var x = document.getElementById("some_div_id").innerHTML;
x = "example"; // this doesn't, it thinks that it's document.getElementById("some_div_id");
```

Took me time to figure what was wrong when I first did the second DOM method.

**Variables are not linked but copied.**

```
var a = 5;
var b = a;
b = 2;
// a: 5
// b: 2
```

As you can see, this doesn't link the value but creates a new one based from it.

**Deep copying from objects trick.**

```
function deepCopy(objValue) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objValue));
}
var obj = {a: 5};
var b = deepCopy(obj.a);
b = 2;
// obj.a: 5
// b: 2
```

This was a trick given to me some time back when I had issues wanting a object value being stored in a variable and edited but without it being linked to the object value. After a while I found I never needed it after improving my coding skills.

Also last note. I read somewhere in clean JavaScript coding that you shouldn't need to use the `new` object method unless it's a `Date()` object or or simulated class, or you may run into typeof and value check issues with `===`.

Can't be certain if this is error free but hope this helps explains better.